# легкое рисование на turtle

Tags: python

мне надо нарисовать с помощью легкого turtle пятиугольник, вот как выглядит изначальный код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надо сделать пятиугольник со стороной 100,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и в чем именно проблема?

Comment: надо нарисовать пятиугольник изменив этот код

Comment: можно код текстом?

Answer (score 2):

неужто совсем так сложно или так лениво и вся надежда на чужого дядю?

google: python turtle выдает первым же сайт

https://server.179.ru/tasks/python/old/turtle.html

на котором приведён код с комментариями из которого нужно понять только `forward` и `left`

а дальше сплошная математика - у правильного пятиугольника сумма углов 360 градусов, значит 1 угол сколько будет? на сколько черепашка должна поворачиваться?

Comment: сумма углов пятиугольника вроде же равна `540`?

Comment: очень неудачно выразился - имел в виду что наша фигура вписана в круг, который 360 градусов и углы фигуры равноудалены друг от друга, т.е. `360 / n`, если бы надо было строить правильный 100 угольник, то пришлось бы поворачивать на 3, 6 градуса каждый раз. По идее нам надо поворачивать на внешний угол фигуры - внутренний угол - это `(n-2)/n*180`, а внешний `180 - (n-2)/n = 180 * 2 / n = 360 / n`, хотя первая формула все таки из второй выведена :))) а не наоборот

Answer (score 1):

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(5):
    pen.forward(100)
    pen.left(72)
```